# what are the reasons for virtualising these instructions?

Tags: x86, virtualization

why is it the below instructions has to be virtualised. How is failing to virtualise this can cause problem.

1. sgdt,sldt,sidt,smsw
2. fcall,longjump,srt
3. lar,verr,verw,lsl
4. pushf, popf, iret

Comment: Imagine what would happen if a client executed, say, `sgdt`.

Comment: I assume `srt` was meant to be `str`. The list in 1 are instructions that could determine privileged state. They don't actually change state but they have access to it. The list in 2 are call and interrupt gate instructions. The list in 3 would allow one to access (read) descriptor information, and the last group allow access to flags from the VMM. So these instructions if not virtualized would be allowed to leak information. The OS would be able to detect that it was running in a virtualized environment. This all becomes an issue if the VMM is running in ring 0 and the OS in a user ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the machine state (segment bases / limits, disabling interrupts, etc.) obviously can't be allowed, or the guest could break out of the VM or at least hang it.  (E.g. by running an infinite loop with interrupts disabled.)

`pushf`/`popf` are slightly subtle: remember that `IF` (the interrupts-enabled bit which `cli`/`sti`  flip) is one of the bits in EFLAGS.

You want the physical machine to have interrupts enabled while the guest disables interrupts.  But you also want the guest to see `IF=0` when it has interrupts disabled on the virtual x86 that it's running on.  So you need to virtualize `pushf` as well as `popf`.

Answer (score 2):

When Intel VMX mode is used for virtualization, which is the case for current virtualization solutions on Intel platforms, none of these instructions need to be virtualized by the VMM, because they do not access or change the protected machine state.

The VMM is allowed (but not required) to request a VM exit for sgdt, sldt, sidt, and str. Other than these, none of the instructions listed ever cause a VM exit.

The processor itself performs minor virtualization of two of these instructions:

- The behavior of SMSW is changed in the guest so that the guest sees
  the value the VMM wants it to.
- The behavior of the IRET instruction is changed in the guest to clear
  NMI blocking.

Comment: The ability to request a VM exit for lgdt, sgdt, lidt, sidt, etc. was not available in the early versions of VMX; it was added later. At the time it was added, I knew what it was useful for, but I don't recall.